# Selenium firefox webdrive does not incorrectly create a screenshot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I take a screenshot of the website (https://allarahealth.com/) with a height of 3000px, but I can't figure out why the screenshot isn't correct. I can't figure out if this is a html layout problem or a Selenium problem?

OS: Ubuntu 22

Selemiun 4

Fifrefox 102

My code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

_w = 1440
_h= 3000
_ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'


opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
opts.add_argument(f"--height={_h}")
opts.add_argument(f"--width={_w}")
opts.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
opts.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
opts.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
opts.add_argument('--disable-blink-features')
opts.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
opts.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
opts.add_argument('disable-infobars')
opts.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.enabled', True)
opts.set_preference('dom.webnotifications.enabled', True)
opts.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
opts.set_preference("general.useragent.override", _ua)
opts.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
opts.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
opts.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
opts.set_preference("browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers", 3)
opts.set_preference("network.dns.disableIPv6", True)
opts.set_preference("Content.notify.interval", 750000)
opts.set_preference("content.notify.backoffcount", 3)

opts.binary_location = r'/opt/firefox/firefox'


ff_path = '/opt/geckodriver'


brws = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, executable_path=ff_path)

time.sleep(1)
brws.get('https://allarahealth.com/')
brws.save_screenshot('screen.png')
brws.close()
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqdRx.jpg)

Comment: I don't know but I might guess it was a responsive site issue. The site is resizing itself to 3000px high which is messing up the flow. Not sure how to solve it... that's just my best guess at what's going wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem because parts of the page appear slowly, try to add `sleep` direct before `save_screenshot`.